# Differentiating between delimiter and newline in getline

Tags: c++, stream, newline, getline

```
ifstream file;
file.open("file.csv");
string str;
while(file.good())
{
    getline(file,str,',')
    if (___) // string was split from delimiter 
    {
        [do this]
    }
    else // string was split from eol
    {
        [do that]
    }
}
file.close();
```

I'd like to read from a csv file, and differentiate between what happens when a string is split off due to a new line and what happens when it is split off due to the desired delimiter -- i.e. filling in the `___` in the sample code above.

The approaches I can think of are:

(1) manually adding a character to the end of each line in the original file,

(2) automatically adding a character to the end of each line by writing to another file,

(3) using `getline` without the delimiter and then making a function to split the resulting string by ','.

But is there a simpler or direct solution?

(I see that similar questions have been asked before, but I didn't see any solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

My preference for clarity of the code would be to use your option 3) - use `getline()` with the standard '\n' delimiter to read the file into a buffer line by line and then use a tokenizer like `strtok()` (if you want to work on the C level) or `boost::tokenizer` to parse the string you read from the file.

You're really dealing with two distinct steps here, first read the line into the buffer, then take the buffer apart to extract the components you're after. Your code should reflect that and by doing so, you're also avoiding having to deal with odd states like the ones you describe where you end up having to do additional parsing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to determine "which delimiter terminated the string", and it gets "consumed" by `getline`, so it's lost to you.

Read the line, and parse split on commas yourself. You can use `std::string::find()` to find commas - however, if your file contains strings that in themselves contain commas, you will have to parse the string character by character, since you need to distinguish between commas in quoted text and commas in unquoted text.

Answer (score 0):

Your big problem is your code does not do what you think it does.

`getline` with a delimiter treats `\n` as just another character from my reading of the docs.  It does not split on both the delimiter and newline.

The efficient way to do this is to write your oen custom splitting getline: cppreference has a pretty clear description of what getline does, mimicing it should be easy (and safer than shooting from the hip, files are tricky).

Then return both the string, and information about why you finished your parse in a second channel.

Now, using getline naively then splitting is also viable, and will be much faster to write, snd probably less error prone to boot.